# comparison with a third variable in priority_queue, c++

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

On this page: http://comsci.liu.edu/~jrodriguez/cs631sp08/c++priorityqueue.html
author gives a nice example of using priority queue in c++. In this the author shows how to order various times serially. I have a similar problem in which I would like to order the times on basis of proximity to a given point in time. My question is how to add a third input to comparer, so that the extra parameter can be considered. I.e. how can we make t3 inside comparer a variable that is passed from outside.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Time {
    int h; // >= 0
    int m; // 0-59
    int s; // 0-59
};

class CompareTime {
public:
    bool operator()(Time& t1, Time& t2)
    {
       Time t3 = {{2,9,0}};

       if (abs(t3.h - t2.h) > (t3.h - t1.h))
         return true;
       return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    priority_queue<Time, vector<Time>, CompareTime> pq;

    // Array of 4 time objects:

    Time t[4] = { {3, 2, 40}, {3, 2, 26}, {5, 16, 13}, {5, 14, 20}};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
       pq.push(t[i]);

    while (! pq.empty()) {
       Time t2 = pq.top();
       cout << setw(3) << t2.h << " " << setw(3) << t2.m << " " <<
       setw(3) << t2.s << endl;
       pq.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

thanks.

Comment: You can just make t3 a member of CompareTime and pass it in the constructor.

Comment: while you're at it, fix your comparator. the operands should be const-ref and the `operator()` itself should be `const` as well.

Comment: And you can just return `abs(t3.h - t2.h) > (t3.h - t1.h)` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparator itself can be parameterized at instantiation:

```
class CompareTime 
{
    Time t;
public:
    CompareTime(const Time& arg) : t{arg} {}

    bool operator()(const Time& t1, const Time& t2) const
    {
        return (abs(t.h - t2.h) > abs(t.h - t1.h));
    }
};
```

Declared like this:

```
    Time myTime; // modify to your leisure...

    // ...then create your queue with myTime as the fixed param
    priority_queue<Time, vector<Time>, CompareTime> pq{CompareTime{myTime};
```

Apologies in advance if the syntax isn't spot-on. I'm without a compiler at this moment, but I hope the idea is clear enough.

Comment: You should change the name of constructor parameter from `t`.

Comment: I wanted to have t3 as a variable that can be controlled on the run time. If I understand your solution correctly, this can only be done at the compile time, and not on the run time. Isnt it?

Comment: @Bonaqa you can pass whatever dynamic `Time` you want to the constructor of `CompareTime` when declaring the priority queue.  But you cannot (and should not want to) change *that* once the priority queue is constructed. If you want to change the comparator contract (which is what you're setting up when you do this) you will need to declare a new queue with a new `CompareTime` and `Time` parameter, and move all your current items to the new queue. But there is nothing stopping you from the `Time` used in this from being runtime-built right up to the moment when the queue is conceived.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. When trying your solution I get a cryptic error message: 
`pq.cpp: In constructor ‘CompareTime::CompareTime(const Time&)’:

 pq.cpp:18:41: error: cannot convert ‘const Time’ to ‘int’ in initialization

CompareTime(const Time& arg) : t{arg} {}
                                         ^`

Comment: Does `Time` support copy construction? It needs to so for this to work. as I said, I'm compiler-agnostic right no. Sorry about that. I also may have missed an inner-set of curlies. (sorry).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, with helpful pointers from WhozCraig and user783920, following solution seems to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


struct Time {
    int h; // >= 0
    int m; // 0-59
    int s; // 0-59
};

class CompareTime 
{
    Time t;
public:
    CompareTime(const Time& arg) {
        std::cout << "struct constructor \n";
        t=arg;
    }
//    CompareTime(){}

    bool operator()(const Time& t1, const Time& t2) const
    {
        return (abs(t.h - t2.h) > abs(t.h - t1.h));
    }
};

int main()
{
    Time mytime ={0};

    mytime.h=6;

    priority_queue<Time, vector<Time>, CompareTime> pq{CompareTime(mytime)};

    // Array of 4 time objects:

    Time t[4] = { {3, 2, 40}, {2, 2, 26}, {5, 16, 13}, {1, 14, 20}};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
       pq.push(t[i]);

    while (! pq.empty()) {
       Time t2 = pq.top();
       cout << setw(3) << t2.h << " " << setw(3) << t2.m << " " <<
       setw(3) << t2.s << endl;
       pq.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```